# Python printing after a while loop, involving sleep statements

Tags: python, while-loop, sleep

I have this function I wrote to do a simple type of half-way search for an integer, as a practice problem. When I run it, I would expect these print statements to be firing after each while loop, however it seems to stall until the correct answer is found, and then print each statement in rapid succession. Does this have to do with the sleep statement or am I missing something here?

```
def start_search(self):
        check_count = 1
        # loop a search function of some kind
        while not self.upper_bound == self.target_number:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            # get middle
            middle = self.get_half(self.lower_bound, self.upper_bound)
            print(f"checking between {self.lower_bound} and {self.upper_bound}")
            # check if target higher or lower than middle
            if middle > self.target_number:
                print(f"Midpoint of {middle} is higher,")
                self.upper_bound = middle
            elif middle < self.target_number:
                print(f"Midpoint of {middle} is lower,")
                self.lower_bound = middle
            else:
                print(f"Found value at midpoint {middle} after {check_count} check(s)")
                self.upper_bound = middle
            check_count += 1
```

Comment: Depending on how you're running your code, your console / terminal might be caching entries before it flushes output. You can use `print("foo", flush=True)` to issue a flush when the print happens. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function

Comment: @MatsLindh I have been running this in vscode, and I thought something like that might be the issue but IDLE also has the same issue for me. I can only really tell this is happening when I use large numbers. I can tell it is taking longer but I don't get the continuous print statements I was looking for. 

flush=True didn't seem to help when I put it on the first print statement of each loop.

Comment: So ... does your `middle = self.get_half(self.lower_bound, self.upper_bound)` suddenly take a lot of time? Use a debugger to step through your code and a profiler to see what's taking up your time. Maybe it's before this function at all, since you don't output anything before the while loop either.

Comment: You can try using `os.environ['PYTHONUNBUFFERED'] = "TRUE")`. However this should have the same effect as using `flush = True` but essentially for every print() statement.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks, I am still getting into this. The debugger made it completely transparent, I don't know why I didn't try that before. It was a function prior to this one that took time to add each number into an array for a different use-case.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't have to do with sleep at all. Debugger made it clear thanks to @MatsLindh that it was a different function stalling the program. Program was bare bones, so I guessed wrong that it was this function stalling everything.

Use your debugger folks.